# CRUD Edit can't retrieve data because of string id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a table called SectionUser like:

SectionUser

- USER_ID (varchar(255))(Primary Key)
- NAME (varchar(255))

Here are sample values:

```
USER ID | NAME

EVTAB | ELMER TABER

FAYKVIL |  FAYK VILLET
```

I have a create action in controller that can create a section user successfully. My main problem is that when I edit. I can't get the value. So for example, I've entered wrong USER_ID and I want to edit it. The USER_ID is always null. This means that I want to edit my primary key.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditUser(string USER_ID)
{
    if (USER_ID == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    SectionUser section = db.SectionUsers.Find(USER_ID);
    if (section == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(section);
}
```

View(cshtml)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditUser", "Admin", FormMethod.Post,
                                  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Section</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.USER_ID)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.USER_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.USER_ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.USER_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NAME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

View(Index)

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.USER_ID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAME)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.USER_ID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditUser", new { id = item.USER_ID.ToString().Trim() }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "DetailsUser", new { id = item.USER_ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteUser", new { id = item.USER_ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: If you enter the wrong user id, what you want to edit ? that user id does not exist in the system

Comment: I can create a user_id and name successfully, so in my index i have edit link to edit the row I want. when i try to run the application in debugging mode, the user_id is null.

Comment: You should be using `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditUser", new { USER_ID = item.USER_ID.ToString().Trim() })`. The name of the parameters must match

Comment: The parameters must match. Change the parameter in the method to `string id` or change the link to `new { user_id = item.USER_ID }`

Comment: And you do not need `.ToString().Trim()`

Comment: Thanks Camilio and Stephen. It wokrs like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my issue here is that the parameters I'm using on index.cshtml is wrong. This is the old code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditUser", new { id = item.USER_ID.ToString().Trim() })
```

New Code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditUser", new { USER_ID = item.USER_ID.ToString().Trim() })
```

As you can see in my EditUser Action, the parameter is string USER_ID.